# Set Error Messages to English Language

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting all error messages from google apps script in russian, even though my google account is set with English as main language. That makes it hard to google the errors. How do I set errors in apps script to English?

```
Не удается вызвать функцию SpreadsheetApp.getUi() из этого контекстного меню. (line 1, file "update_spreadsheet")
```

Comment: I'm guessing that when you create your Google account, the default language is set by Google depending upon what part of the world the account was created from.  Apps Script doesn't have a setting for the default language.  So, if the account was created in a country where Russian is the default language, you might not be able to change the language of the Apps Script errors.  If this is an add-on, then even though your default language may be something different, if the add-on user is in a Russian speaking country the errors would be in Russian.  I don't think you can change that.

Comment: You can get the language code with `Session.getActiveUserLocale()`  Even though the method name uses the word "Locale" it's not really a location, but a language code.  But there is no method to set the language code.

Comment: Sad to hear that, it really slows down my development process, as I can't easily find related information. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: You should have error handling in your code that gives you the line number of the error.  You can get the line number from the error object caught by a "try/catch" block.  `try{ your code } catch(e) {myErrorHandlingFuntion(e)}`  Pass all the errors to one function, that then sends the information to you.  You can get the stack with `e.stack`

Comment: Is your project a bounded or standalone project?

Comment: Take a look to this https://github.com/RomainVialard/ErrorHandler

Comment: it's a spreadsheet add-on with time-driven events.